# How Spring async with Callable work and what I do not understand?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I am reading SpringMVC docs and I get stucked in asynchronous section: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-async

I created very simple project (Spring 4, Java 8) as follows with such controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/async")
    public Callable<String> async() {
        logger.info("Async IN, {}", new Date());
        return () -> {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return "home";
        };
    }

    @RequestMapping("/sync")
    public String sync() throws Exception {
        logger.info("Sync IN, {}", new Date());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return "home";
    }

}
```

I have enabled async feature in Servlet - as described in docs. Now I call requests, firstly to `/sync` and secondly to `/async`. One after another. They are all being dispatched immedietaly. Spring app is not waiting for `/sync` to end before it will start to process `/async` requests. I get response in same time after requests.

It looks like this:

```
INFO : com.mydlarz.springtt.HomeController - Sync IN, Thu Dec 04 17:00:18 CET 2014
INFO : com.mydlarz.springtt.HomeController - Async IN, Thu Dec 04 17:00:19 CET 2014
INFO : com.mydlarz.springtt.HomeController - Async IN, Thu Dec 04 17:00:29 CET 2014
INFO : com.mydlarz.springtt.HomeController - Sync IN, Thu Dec 04 17:00:29 CET 2014
```

Why is that? The second request handling should not be started about 5 sec after the first SYNC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronous and asynchronous are meant in respect to the thread used by the Servlet container. Synchronous requests will use up that thread, blocking it if necessary for other operations to complete. An asynchronous request, will use up the thread, but will not block it. Operations will move to another thread where blocking can happen.

> Why is that? The second request handling should not be started about 5 sec after the first SYNC?

If you have more than 4 threads in your Servlet container (very likely), none of your 4 requests will wait for any other.

Comment: @DariuszMydlarz There's no standard way to do it. It depends on your Servlet container.

Comment: @DariuszMydlarz what you can do to simulate the request getting backed up is to add `synchronized` in front of each of the methods ie `public synchronized String sync()`. But don't leave the `synchronized` in for production.